# chrome.windows and chrome.tabs are returning undefined in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm running the following code in my background.js script, but it's hitting a bug with chrome on the second line.

```js
console.log(chrome.windows, chrome.tabs);
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, getAllOpenWindows);
function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {
  var tabs = [];
  for (var i in winData) {
    if (winData[i].focused === true) {
      var winTabs = winData[i].tabs;
      var totTabs = winTabs.length;
      for (var j=0; j<totTabs;j++) {
        tabs.push(winTabs[j].url);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(tabs);
}
```

When I run it, the console.log in line 1 return `undefined undefined` and the whole thing errors at line 2.

My manifest.json is as follows:

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Muter",
    "description": "Fill in",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_title": "Muter"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you looking in the right console, though? How do you open the console to look at the logs?

Comment: @Xan I open the console with command+option+j

Comment: Then you are opening the current page's console, and not your background page's console. This code won't work in a normal page, just as you described. You need to go to to `chrome://extensions/` and click the "background page" link for your extension.